# Retrigger masonry.js with infinite scroll jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

I'm working on a Tubmlr site for a friend and they use masonry as well as infinite scroll plugin.

The scroll plugin is a script pulled in from a third party and the masonry is fired on the page...

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.autopagerize_page_element').masonry();        
    });
```

When the scroll reloads more posts however the masonry plugin doesnt work, im guessing this is because it needs to be re-triggered again only im unsure how?

Ive tried using

```
setInterval(function(){
    // masonry
},100);
```

to keep checking only ive had no luck, can anybody give ma any idea ?

Comment: Did you check here http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html?

Comment: A link to the tumblr would be helpful. Anyway, The infinite scroll script should allow you to provide a callback function (or trigger an event) when the next page is "finished" loading. In that callback function you could call `$('.autopagerize_page_element').masonry('reload');` or, if the callback provides the new post elements added to the page, you could call `$('.autopagerize_page_element').masonry('appended',$newPosts);`.  Using an interval with `setInterval` is **not** a good way to go about this!